# Sort A-Z and Z-A in an array on clicking bootstrap dropdown

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am showing a list of heros in template and I want to filter them by their name when i will toggele the dropdown A-Z and Z-A. Please suggest.

```
<template>
   <div>
     <ul>
       <li v-for="(hero, index) in list" :key="index">{{hero.name}}</li>
     </ul>
   </div>
</template>



data() {
    return {
      list: [
        {id: 1, name: 'Captain America'},
        {id: 2, name: 'hulk'},
        {id: 3, name: 'Captain marvel'},
        {id: 4, name: 'iron man'},
        {id: 5, name: 'black widow'},
        {id: 6, name: 'ant man'}
      ]
    };
  }


<div class="dropdown show">
   <a class="sorting-title" href="javascript:void(0)" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown">a - z</a>
     <div class="dropdown-menu sorting-dropdown" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)">a - z</a>
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)">z - a</a>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list.sort((a,b)=>{
  if(a.name.toUpperCase() < b.name.toUpperCase()) { return -1; }
    if(a.name.toUpperCase() > b.name.toUpperCase()) { return 1; }
    return 0;
})

//To Get the vice versa just interchange the less than (<) and greater than sign (>)
```

The result will be [image]

You can assign it to a new data and put it inside your dropdown. Maybe sort your data inside mounted.

Comment: Right now I am showing them in v-for. After shorting should i have to re render the list?

Comment: You can do it like this one.

mounted() {
this.sortedAZ = list.sort((a,b)=>{
  if(a.name.toUpperCase() < b.name.toUpperCase()) { return -1; }
    if(a.name.toUpperCase() > b.name.toUpperCase()) { return 1; }
    return 0;
})
}


And then in your v-for just use the sortedAZ


Or you can sort it after clicking the dropdown

Comment: Its working but when i am getting the array then it is showing me this error - "do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers"

Comment: methods: {

    sortAZ(){
      this.getAllHeros.sort((a,b)=>{
        if(a.name.toUpperCase() < b.name.toUpperCase()) { return -1; }
          if(a.name.toUpperCase() > b.name.toUpperCase()) { return 1; }
          return 0;
      })
    }
  
}


computed: {
    ...mapGetters({getAllHeros : 'getAllHeros'}),
  }